# @Autowired object is null when working with @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, spring-boot-test

So I am trying to autowire my http object in my test class and I have tried to integrate with @SpringBootTest however my http object still remains null.

My test class looks like this.

```
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Http.class)
public class GetItemTests {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetItemTests.class);

@Autowired
private Http httpClass;
}
```

My SpringBootMain class looks like this

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMain implements CommandLineRunner {

@Bean
ResourceConfig resourceConfig() {
    return new ResourceConfig().registerClasses(Version1Api.class,TokenUtilityClass.class, Paypal.class);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    //test.authenticationToken();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMain.class);
}
}
```

I have tried running with the SpringRunner as well as this but I receive errors about failing to load the application context.

Comment: When do you get the errors, is it when you run the spring boot app or the test?
Could you post the error logs?

Comment: Also curious, why would you want to autowire Http class in your test class?

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` is useless. The `@Autowired` field cannot be null as it would fail with an error during startup not while running the test.

Comment: You should create the real object for a class under test. You should not autowire

Comment: @codeMan 
My error when a run the test is simple it is a Java null pointer exception. 
I want to autowire the HTTP class as it uses an external config class which populates some of the HTTP's values from the an application.properties file

Answer (score 0):

Unless your `Http` class is annotated with `@Component` (meaning it is a bean maintained by the Spring IoC Container) you will not be able to `@Autowire` it in the way you wrote.

Please also post the exception you are getting and the implementation of your `Http` class so we can potentially provide further help.

Comment: This is not an answer, please post this as a comment!